# Regular Expression - search until specific string appears

Tags: regex, linux, grep, rtmp, ngrep

I'm using `ngrep` and `grep` to extract some strings out of network traffic:

```
sudo ngrep -W byline | grep...
```

Now I want grep to search for a string and copy from first letter on until some different string appears. Strings are `rtmp` and `..`
For example:

```
"fwef-$*nVrtmp://Ggdggragravrv.com/lolwtf.mp5skill0rz%%&:/getr4kt..Glub"
```

should turn into:

```
"rtmp://Ggdggragravrv.com/lolwtf.mp5skill0rz%%&:/getr4kt"
```

Is this possible in any way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try the below grep command which uses a [positive lookahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) based regex,

```
$ echo "fwef-$*nVrtmp://Ggdggragravrv.com/lolwtf.mp5skill0rz%%&:/getr4kt..Glub" | grep -oP 'rtmp.*?(?=\.\.)'
rtmp://Ggdggragravrv.com/lolwtf.mp5skill0rz%%&:/getr4kt
```

Comment: Update your question with the exact input.

Comment: @RainerZufall - what do you mean ".." before rtmp ? Could it be either `..   rtmp` or `rtmp  ..` or even `rtmp  rtmp` or `.. ..` ?

Comment: @sln
OK, thanks so far.
What about this one?

input:
"......mp3:mp3/19695c8f0fcbe45521908c3ec60f8f96554a523e?Expires=1421093669&Signature=KstuSlKVypnPEF6Ird.zT52iys5yNCGVIPV1PfMCk35ZMdBPCKmnqVdKp1QjQpT8aBp4MlBHAriQjlFCDEwq98ZiFXctlDxdADDeiAlkOu0ByOWDjlCA9zn1LEmiqHIQlmqb0FsruhaD~XaqL1G.BbuQoZ6sGZw12jsgA1YIv8JgDXafQrDcU9HL1yja~8pAAr6lsarl7q3kb97oqJhTGecBYqlqA0dcuDig0A62BQJYxqGk84xfDy6jpbtQrAu4IqLdxVZqw98b4W0oQtMP.qbtyreZ-eaVdFN0rP2MDevoIwSAJv0~O5MEiTp0yOxCF764F0PBrnuMWUPLnyhnt~QWg__&Key-Pair-Id=APKAJXKSII4ED2EOGZZA#"


output: mp3/ until # but not including #

Comment: @RainerZufall - `mp3/[^#]*(?=#)`

Answer (score 0):

This covers `rtmp to just before` ..
*and* `.. to just before` rtmp.
*and*  `rtmp to just before` rtmp,
*and*  `.. to just before` ..

```
 # (?:rtmp|\.\.)(?:(?!rtmp|\.\.).)*(?=\.\.|rtmp)

 (?: rtmp | \.\. )
 (?:
      (?! rtmp | \.\. )
      . 
 )*
 (?= \.\. | rtmp )
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have perl(-compatible) regular expressions available, you can do the match with ordinary egrep. However, you have to figure out the inverse of the terminating expression. For example, if a string terminates just before `..`, then it matches any sequence which does not contain `..`, which means that it matches any character which is not a period, or a period followed by a character which is not a period. That's the same as saying "an optional period followed by a non-period":

```
$ echo "fwef-$*nVrtmp://Ggdggragravrv.com/lolwtf.mp5skill0rz%%&:/getr4kt..Glub" |
> grep -oE 'rtmp:([.]?[^.])*'
rtmp://Ggdggragravrv.com/lolwtf.mp5skill0rz%%&:/getr4kt
```

If the terminating string is a single character, that's even easier: just match anything other than the terminator. For example, to match a string up to but not including a `?`:

```
$ echo "......mp3:mp3/19695c8f0fcbe45521908c3ec60f8f96554a523e?Expires=1421093669&..." |
> grep -oE 'mp3/[^?]*'
mp3/19695c8f0fcbe45521908c3ec60f8f96554a523e
```